# JavaScript Generated Fields Visible Briefly on Page Load in WP Tool

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress theme where I include an external tool using require_once 'lib/packages/tool/init.php' in my functions.php file. Inside this tool, I have a src/tool.php file where I enqueue some JavaScript scripts using the wp_enqueue_script function. The JavaScript code randomizes the position of certain form fields, but these fields should be hidden from the user's view as soon as the page loads. However, there is a brief moment after the page loads where the generated fields are visible and then disappear.

Here's the relevant code in my src/tool.php file:

```
public function enqueueScripts()
{
    $file_url = $this->file_path_to_url(dirname((__FILE__), 2));
    wp_enqueue_script('field-randomizer', $file_url . '/assets/js/field-randomizer.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
}
```

I've been trying to enqueue the scripts asynchronously using the true argument in wp_enqueue_script, but this hasn't resolved the issue of the generated fields briefly appearing on page load.

In addition to this, I have also tried enqueuing the scripts inside my functions.php file, but the problem still persists.

I would like to know how to prevent this brief visibility of the generated fields on page load. Is there a way to ensure that the JavaScript code executes quickly and hides these fields immediately upon page load?

Any advice or suggestions on optimizing the JavaScript execution, using asynchronous loading, or changing the way I'm enqueuing the script would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to hide the fields with CSS by default:

```css
.your-field.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

And then in your JS after you finish your randomization logic remove the default hiding:

```js
$(".your-field.hidden").removeClass("hidden");
```